# Meaning of "catch birds for"?

Tags: meaning, literature

I am reading B. Traven's adventure *The Treasure of the Sierra Madre*, which is about three men who secretly go prospecting for gold. On their way home with their new-found loot they cover their tracks by tearing down their mining camp. Howard (the most experienced of the party) verbally beams with pride over a job well done. Dobbs, another member, takes offense at Howard's response. [The quoted section can be found here](http://books.google.com/books?id=0bOCW5J02MkC&pg=PA184&dq=%22to+catch+birds+for%22+treasure+of+sierra+madre&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YQD0Ua2SNIezyAGkrIDgCg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20catch%20birds%20for%22%20treasure%20of%20sierra%20madre&f=false):

> The mine was leveled to the satisfaction of Howard. Anybody now coming upon the mine by chance would never think that a mine had been worked here, or if at all, not during the last hundred years.
>
> "Doesn't it give you guys a real joy to look at the place now?" Howard asked with pride in his voice.
>
> "All right," Dobbs said, "you have it your way and you feel happy, so please, for the love of Mike's booze, leave us in peace with your feelings. Sometimes I think you must have been a preacher, only the hell of it is I can't figure out what church it was you wanted to catch birds for."

When I found a definition of [*bird*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bird) (Definition 5.a) that is slang for *fellow*, I took Dobbs' words *to catch birds for* to be reminiscent of the Christian saying *fisher of men*, meaning the minister is actively looking for people to convert. In past conversations, Dobbs has been known to use slang like *mug* to refer to people. But being more familiar with the usages meaning [*a young woman* or *a person, especially one who is odd or remarkable*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bird), I thought this usage unlikely and continued to look for another.

So I wondered if Dobbs was making an allusion to [bird dogs](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bird-dog), who retrieve birds for their masters. (One might say a minister *retrieves* the lost for a higher power, a superior in the church or for God.) This could be an insult to Howard, the slight being that Howard would be a subordinate instead of the senior/equal he was when mining with Dobbs. This insult makes sense in this context, because Dobbs has a history of viewing Howard as a taskmaster, as shown by Dobbs's outburst when he cuts his own hand at the beginning of the chapter. But this analogy of bird dogs seems tenuous and elaborate.

I've searched Google for "catching birds," but the most relevant results are the proverb "A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush." I wondered if Dobbs was speaking of some duty, tradition, or superstition associated with ministers, but I have found nothing.

What does "to catch birds for" mean?

Comment: Could you add a bit more of the dialogue before the phrase in question? Offhand I can’t think of any better explanations than what you’ve already come up with, but more context might bring on an epiphany.

Comment: I don't understand why you describe "bird == fellow" as "unlikely"; the dictionary says it's been used that way, and you don't seem to offer any reason to disbelieve the dictionary on this point . . .

Comment: Is it possible to tell (from the story) what religion or faith Dobbs and Howard belong to? I've not read the book myself.

Comment: http://www.satodayscatholic.com/Heitkamp_100711.aspx Priests (?) who annually hunt doves in South Texas for the past 74 years

Comment: It could be that in the US Catholic priests used to capture doves before celebrating Easter, and then released them at the end of the Holy Mass to symbolise the ascent of the Holy spirit or something like that. I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: I think you're onto something, @Mari-LouA. At least one member of the party (Curtin) is from TX, so that first link could make some sense. It says first *annual* hunt was 1930s, but this takes place in 1920s. But maybe Dobbs caught wind of it from the native Curtin before it was an organized event. (The mining party had been working together for some time by this point.) My opinion is all the members are nonreligious. They have been working/living in areas that have had Catholic influences, so European traditions make sense too.

Comment: Well doves are birds and were *usually* caught, not killed (!), by Italian priests to celebrate Easter.

Comment: By any chance is either Dobbs or Howard Irish by descent? Are their surnames Irish?

Comment: I don't remember seeing anything about the members' heritages, but I will keep an eye out for it and other clues. (I should probably have saved this question for when I finished the book. I may refrain from further updates until I have finished.) Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine it's an echo of this expression (as defined by OED)...

> *(strictly) **for the birds***
>    trivial, worthless; appealing only to ***gullible people***. orig. and chiefly U.S. colloq.

Dobbs clearly isn't interested in anything Howard has to say. He's implying that despite Howard's ["evangelical"](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061130091631AAaHmgs) enthusiasm, nobody else would be interested either, except *gullible people* as above.

OP is on the right track with *bird = fellow* - but here it's specifically [birdbrained](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/birdbrain) *(stupid)* fellows. The word *catch* is also used figuratively here (Dobbs means *interest, draw in, captivate, impress*).

Comment: This makes sense too. Dobbs strikes me as a cynical personality. More than that, the party has just escaped the clutches of a vicious gang of thieves that devastated a train stealing gold for God. It's a confusing situation and it's unclear at the moment what Dobbs's opinion is on what's causing the violence (Howard, for instance, seems to blame gold over religion). Dobbs may be taking out his frustration on religion here.

Comment: @dingo_dan: I haven't read the book, but [in the movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040897/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl) Dobbs is as cynical as any character played by Humphrey Bogart. He definitely wouldn't have any time for religion, churches, preachers, etc.

Comment: Yes, but Dobbs is aiming his criticism at *Howard*.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: True, but I think it's clear that when he says to Howard *"I think you must have been a preacher"* he intends this as an ***insult*** (he doesn't really believe Howard was ever part of organised religion).

Comment: Exactly, an insult. Hence, bird, instead of "dove".

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Your answer, drawing a link between Dobbs's *birds* and the use of *doves* in certain [sometimes, religious] ceremonies, is "interesting". But I don't think it's got any connection with either what Dobbs the fictional character or Traven the author actually meant by the usage here.

Comment: I'd say my answer is not only "interesting" but it's a valid and legitimate one.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: What can I say? Apart from pointing out that's the first answer of yours I've *ever* downvoted, because I think it's totally wrong.

Comment: I have no problem with that. Absolutely fine. I think it's "possible" you may be right.

Comment: Another thing to bear in mind is that the author is almost certainly not a native speaker. His *for the love of Mike's **booze*** is the only instance in Google Books (but there are apparently 231,000 *without* that anomalous "booze"). Equally, I've been unable to find any other written instances of *catching birds for a church*. In the real world I'd have thought the doves released at ceremonies are tame ones anyway, that will simply fly back to their dovecote ready to be used again next Easter. It seems unlikely *any* churches would sanction bird trapping these days.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "almost certainly not a native speaker"? The author, Traven, is of questionable origin (both who that name is attached to and for any given individual attached to unsubstantiated past), the book was originally in German, and so was translated. There are so many layers of unknowns that any inference is speculation at best.

Comment: Idiosyncrasies in Dobbs's speech (*birds* and not *doves*, adding *booze* into *love of Mike*) I think are a device the author uses to show how crass or vulgar Dobbs is. Based on the lack of (recorded) immediate reaction from Howard, though, I wonder if this was an entendre on Dobbs's part: Taking shots at Howard, the church and its followers, but not in an outright way. On the other hand, I may have misread it. Maybe Dobbs is humorously complimenting Howard, like patting him on the back while saying it. Traven leaves no explicit cues as to how the passage should be read.

Comment: @dingo_dan: The reference to birds is just a one-off - nothing odd about that (there never was any related expression involving *doves*). Maybe Dobbs says *Mike's **booze*** because he's wishing he had some, I don't know. Anyway, I just found [an online copy](http://libcom.org/library/treasure-sierra-madre-b-traven), from which it's obvious in the next chapter that the author likes taking pops at representatives of organised religion - *the holy persons who take care of [a local icon] and are in charge of everything, **including collecting the fees***.

Comment: @Mitch: I now realise you're right. Little indeed is what we know about the guy. I just saw Wikipedia's *B. Traven was the pen name of a presumably German novelist* and assumed Traven wrote the book *in English*, which wasn't his native language. Wikipedia says that scenario is "not taken seriously", and that his books were translated from German originals. Travens himself may have been a fluent Anglophone, and he may have done the translating. Or maybe his wife did, or someone else. I've no idea, and five minutes on Google suggests no-one else "knows" either.

Comment: This answer has the most evidence going for it: Another instance of Dobbs' Christianity-is-for-the-gullible attitude is in Ch. 20, when Dobbs suspects Curtin of trying to kill him and says, "Didn't I judge you right, son of a stinking dog?... Talking Bolshevik Sunday school. You can't smoke me, brother, with sweet love-songs." Also, in my research, I found a similar phrase *to catch gulls* used with exactly this intention in a translation of Gaston Leroux's [*Phantom of the Opera*](http://goo.gl/OcyHbm). Thanks!

Comment: @dingo_dan: That's an interesting "related" link! I found a couple of instances of [to catch gulls for](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to+catch+gulls+for%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books which clearly don't directly relate to ornithology. I wonder if ***gulls*** in that context also alludes to the word ***gullible***?

Comment: Good point. It looks like [*gullible*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gullibility&allowed_in_frame=0) may have been derived from this meaning of [*gull*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gull).

Comment: @dingo_dan: Etymologically, *gull = [type of bird]* is unrelated to *gullible* as in *one who will "swallow" anything (down his **gullet**)*. That second one also gives us *gull = cheat, swindle, deceive, beguile, hoax, trick, fool*, but you can easily see how people would conflate the two senses.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that in the US Catholic priests used to capture doves before celebrating Easter, and then released them at the end of the Holy Mass to symbolise the ascension of the Holy Spirit.

In [Italy](http://goitaly.about.com/od/festivalsandevents/a/easter.htm) there are several festivals that celebrate Easter by releasing doves in the air. I was wondering if they did the same in the US.

**La Madonna Che Scappa in Piazza** - Abruzzo Region

> Sulmona, in the Abruzzo region, celebrates Easter Sunday with "La
> Madonna Che Scappa in Piazza"
>
> "On Easter Sunday people dress in green and white, colors of peace,
> hope, and resurrection, and gather in the main piazza. The woman
> playing the Virgin Mary is dressed in black. As she moves to the
> fountain, doves are released and the woman is suddenly dressed in
> green.

I found this [Youtube](http://www.myluso.com/i-e-s-festa-2013-playing-of-the-anthems-and-releasing-of-the-holy-ghost-doves-today/) clip filmed at Santa Jose, 2013, entitled: "The releasing of the holy ghost doves today." Skip to the 3.40 mark to see the dove being freed. The video is very dull and amateurish but it proves (to me) that even today, in some parts of the US, this tradition still carries on.

EDIT:

> I think you must have been a preacher, only the hell of it is I can't figure out what church it was you wanted to catch birds for.

Dobbs insults Howard by calling him a preacher this leads me to speculate that Dobbs was not "born" in the Catholic faith, (priests are not normally referred to as preachers) however, by mentioning *birds* and asking who Howard caught them for, it is possible that either he was familiar with the Easter festival tradition of releasing *live* doves in  the air or maybe he was attempting to cover up his background by ridiculing his (plausible) religious upbringing.

Not having read the book I can only make suppositions, but the dots do connect.

Comment: This meshes with the story really well. Do the ministers do the actual catching? If not, it may be Dobbs's error.

Comment: No, not any more. I don't know if the doves are bought, or kept in coops today in those regional festivals which still uphold that tradition. The majority of Catholic churches in the North of Italy no longer follow that practice.

Comment: @dingo_dan I'm not 100% certain about priests actually capturing the doves, but if you recall the first link I posted there are priests in Texas who hunt and kill these birds today. So if a so called priest can kill an innocent animal, it's logical to presume that in *the past* (no longer true in Italy at least) some actually captured these birds.

Comment: I have finished the book. It's hinted that Dobbs' mother, who knows what real haggis tastes like, is Scottish (Ch. 23). Howard and Dobbs may have been raised Protestant: Howard thinks he can convincingly bluff government officials into thinking he is a Baptist preacher (Ch. 18); Dobbs refers to "Sunday school" (Chs. 19, where he ridicules his religious upbringing by calling his teacher a "dried-up hussy," & 20), and strangers who waylay him label him as Protestant (Ch. 24). Also, I think it's plausible the men came across this or some other rite in their travels. Thanks!

Comment: So I was right! (Well, I think so considering all the references to religion) Thanks for letting me know.